# Combine Many XML Files

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

What language can I use to combine multiple XML files. Multiple as 10+ files.

PHP, java, or what?

I tried to use XSLT but I do not know if I need a 'processor' such as Saxon.

The docs were to confusing as I did not know where to start.

All in all, I need someone to point me in the right direction.

Someone please help. I've been trying to figure this out for days

```
<xml version="1.0">
<products>
<price>Price List Here</price>
<model>Model Number Here</model>
</product>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a comlete, short and easy pure XSLT solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any language that allows you to manipulate xml directly.  I suggest finding something with DOM rather than SAX.  If you use SAX you have to basically traverse the xml yourself - a pita in my experience.  DOM allows you to act on the xml in a more OOP manner.

Something that springs immediately to mind would be a wrapper xml around your xml "documents".

So something like:

```
<documents>
   <document>
      <!-- Your xml here -->
   </document>
   <document>
      <!-- Your xml here -->
   </document>
   <document>
      <!-- Your xml here -->
   </document>
</documents>
```

The pseudo code would be:
Create a document root.
Add an element called documents, use that as the root.
Iterate each of your xml files.
For each file create a new element called document.  Add that element to the parent.  Load the xml from the file.  Import that node into the outer document. Append the imported node into the document elements child collection.

**EDIT**
As promised here is the updated code that was tested and I know works:

```
<?php

    // Replace the strings below with the actual filenames, add or decrease as fit
    $filenames = array(0 => "test.xml", 1 => "test2.xml", 2 => "test3.xml" );

    $docList = new DOMDocument();

    $root = $docList->createElement('documents');
    $docList->appendChild($root);

    foreach($filenames as $filename) {

        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->load($filename);

        $xmlString = $doc->saveXML($doc->documentElement);

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
        $query = "//product";  // this is the name of the ROOT element

        $nodelist = $xpath->evaluate($query, $doc->documentElement);

        if( $nodelist->length > 0 ) {

            $node = $docList->importNode($nodelist->item(0), true);

            $xmldownload = $docList->createElement('document');
            $xmldownload->setAttribute("filename", $filename);
            $xmldownload->appendChild($node);

            $root->appendChild($xmldownload);
        }

    }

    echo $docList->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But this seems like a lot of manual work. I am automatically downloading these XML files each day, and I do not want to edit each individual XML file

Comment: @RPM I didn't mean for you to hand edit them.  Check out my pseudo code.  If you have a process that downloads them then that same process can convert them to the structure above.  That was never intended to be a manual operation.  As for stripping out the <?xml tags, that can also be done through code.

Comment: If by chance you know or have done this via PHP could you shed some light on it. I can provide you with the current XML structure (all 10 files follow the EXACT same structure)-- This sounds like it should be extremely simple but I have been having a difficult experience in trying to accomplish it.

Comment: @RPM Sure, no problem. I'll put some code in the post that will help you out.

Comment: @SRM I've updated my post with the structure for each of my files. The downloaded files currently have a style sheet parameter in them, but would that be a problem?

Comment: @RPM I think your xml got whacked by the formatter.  Try highlighting it and clicking the code button - the one that looks like '{}'.

Comment: @RPM as long as they are all valid xml markup, that won't be a problem.

Comment: @RPM updated based on your xml (the root element name was the most important).  That code should work for you.

Comment: @SRM  $xmlarray[your_index] do I need to define a file for that element?

Comment: @RPM No, your_index is anything you want to use for the index.  It could be the filename, a numeric index, whatever makes sense to you later on if you might need to refer to it by index.  In this case you can just use a counter since you are done with the array once it's processed and won't be holding on to it any longer than that.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your time. I'm trying to debug the script because It is not working. [I copied it exactly and replaced the $xml with my files]

Comment: @RPM That would be because I wrote a bug :).  The assignment to $xmlarray[your_index] was incorrect.  Take a look now, I've made an edit.

Comment: @RPM Make that two bugs!  Wow, I should have tested this first, sorry about that.  I'm not at a place where I can test easily right now though.  If you are still struggling, when I get home tonight I'll make sure I post something that works.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Yeah this is not working at all. Thanks for the time, I appreciate this.

Comment: @RPM Hmm, can't send personal messages here, so this ends up being a chat conversation as a list of messages :).  I made a couple more changes.  There were quite a few bugs.  That's what happens when you cut and paste from three different sources.  Like I said, I'll test this and fix if necessary and post later when it's done.  Sorry about that.

Comment: If you can email me it my email is -- vbizmarketing@ymail.com

Comment: how about just using vim and doing some cutting and pasting?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author The OP doesn't want it to be a manual process.

Comment: @vtd-xml-author I need it to be a automated process in order to update my database. I'm working with data that gets updated everyday. And I want to able to update my database with a single 5 minute operation rather than copy/pasting 10+ files.

Answer (score 7):

**This can be done easily in pure XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pdoc1Url" select="'doc1.xml'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pdoc2Url" select="'doc2.xml'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <documents>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document($pdoc1Url)"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document($pdoc2Url)"/>
  </documents>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The code above deals with two XML documents, but can be extended to deal with any, known in advance number of XML documents.

**Explanation**:

1. Passing the URLs for the XML documents as global/external parameters to the transformation.
2. Use of the standard XSLT function **[`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-document)**.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now, Do I just execute this file in a browser? Please excuse my lack of understanding regarding XSLT

Comment: You should have said that you need the transformation performed in a browser. This is usually done with Javascript code on page load or at other appropriate event. Also, if the URLs are referencing files in the local file system, it is likely the access to the files will not be granted -- as any attempt to do this, regardles of the programming language. As to how external parameters are passed to the transformation, this is different for different XSLT processors. One has to read the documentation of the XSLT processor they are using, to understand how external parameters should be passed.