# Combine multiple XML URLs into one XML file with PHP + XSLT

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I'm trying to combine multiple, smaller XML files into one large XML.

I have done some searching and am trying to use PHP / XML / XSL but I can't seem to get it right.

I'm using:

```
<?php

// Load the XML source
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('collection.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('vp.xsl');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); // attach the xsl rules

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);

?>
```

And here is the XSL file I'm using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="pdoc1Url" select="'http://www.domainname.com/pages/google-feed?page=1.xml'"/>
<xsl:param name="pdoc2Url" select="'http://www.domainname.com/pages/google-feed?page=2.xml'"/> 
<xsl:param name="pdoc3Url" select="'http://www.domainname.com/pages/google-feed?page=3.xml'"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<documents>
<xsl:copy-of select="document($pdoc1Url)"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="document($pdoc2Url)"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="document($pdoc3Url)"/>
</documents>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However when I run the script nothing is combining? I know I'm doing something wrong but can't seem to find out exactly what that is. I think I'm using the PHP XSLT Processor incorrectly.

What is the best way to combine XML documents from multiple URLs into 1 xml? They all have the same formatting. Ideally I'd like to be able to view the combined XML from a URL.

The data I'm trying to combine is like these two URLs for example:
http://www.domainname.com/pages/google-feed?page=1.xml
http://www.domainname.com/pages/google-feed?page=2.xml

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT: A simple way to merge xml files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510688/xslt-a-simple-way-to-merge-xml-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to perform your transformation using Saxon 6.5.4. The transformation took more than 14 seconds on a fast 12GB RAM computer. 108209 lines were produced (and thus I am not placing the output here ... :)  ).

There is an error in `http://www.vitaminpartners.com/pages/google-feed?page=1.xml` but Saxon recovered from this error. Quite probably the XSLT processor you are using doesn't recover from this error, or the computer you are using lacks enough memory.

**Here are the messages from Saxon**:

```
SAXON 6.5.4 from Michael Kay
Java version 1.6.0_31
Preparation time: 90 milliseconds
Processing file:/(Untitled)
Building tree for file:/(Untitled) using class com.icl.saxon.tinytree.TinyBuilder
Tree built in 6 milliseconds
Building tree for http://www.vitaminpartners.com/pages/google-feed?page=1.xml using class com.icl.saxon.tinytree.TinyBuilder
Error on line 28088 column 21 of http://www.vitaminpartners.com/pages/google-feed?page=1.xml:
  Error reported by XML parser: unexpected character after entity reference (found "<") (expected ";")
Recoverable error
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: unexpected character after entity reference (found "<") (expected ";")
Building tree for http://www.vitaminpartners.com/pages/google-feed?page=2.xml using class com.icl.saxon.tinytree.TinyBuilder
Tree built in 6936 milliseconds
Building tree for http://www.vitaminpartners.com/pages/google-feed?page=3.xml using class com.icl.saxon.tinytree.TinyBuilder
Tree built in 4350 milliseconds
Execution time: 14845 milliseconds
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Thank Dimitre, I figured it would be a big job but for as often as it needs to be run it isn't a big deal for me. I was actually looking at this post you posted on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916408/combine-many-xml-files?answertab=active#tab-top  I was hoping to use your answer with a PHP XSLT processor.

Comment: @MikeAverto: Yes, the solution would be identical -- the only problem is that in this particular case one of the resources represented by the urls isn't a well-formed XML document -- hence the raised error. You need to use a tool that will correct any non-well-formedness errors as a preprocessing pass (or in the worst case, do these corrections manually) -- or use Saxon -- as I did.

Comment: Ok thanks. What command did you use in Saxon since there is really only a XSL stylesheet and an output needed?

Comment: @MikeAverto: You can execute Saxon from the command line -- read about this here: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.5/using-xsl.html  . I am using something like this: `java com.icl.saxon.StyleSheet -t  %1 %2 > %3`  -- not shure if %1 / %2 is the XML or the stylesheet.

Comment: I was reading about it there. I ended up using the windows command line version and executed in the bin folder with: Transform.exe -s:merge.xsl -xsl:merge.xsl -o:outputfile.xml. It still worked with the error you mentioned above. Thanks again.